# Grails g:Button name coming from params and no form to use

Tags: grails, controller

Is there any possibility of having a button which will execute and action in a controller without a form ?. Also, i would like do do something like this, but i see that's not possible:

```
<g:form action="addFavourite">
                                                <td>
        <g:submitButton name="${it.area.name}" value="Add" class="button small blue"/><br><br>
        </td>
                       </g:form>
```

To name the button with a value that comes from a controller isnt working. Any possible alternative for that? It gives me a null-error-code. And i'm 100% sure the value isnt null..

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you're asking here. In the text of your question you say you want to use a button without a form, but your code shows a button inside a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of depends.  If you want a button to submit to a server via a standard POST then no.  HTML doesn't even have a button that works without a form.  You can fake this with an image link that looks like a button, but really it just submits via a standard anchor tag.  And this would perform a GET, not a POST.

However, if you want to use ajax, you could skip the Grails tags (as I often do) and use the HTML BUTTON element.  Could even use the remoteFunction to make the ajax call if you want.

UPDATE: Doh!  2 of the same answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a button outside a form that executes a controller action when it's clicked using the [remoteFunction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) tag

```
<button type="button" name="myButton"
    onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'bookByName', controller: 'book'
    params:'\'bookName=\' + this.value')}">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: and how about using g:submit form. is there any possibility i can name that button with a ${it.anem} format?

Comment: You can name the button whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

What does "it" stands here for? I think that is the culprit..

```
<g:submitButton name="${it.area.name}" value="Add" class="button small blue"/>
```